# Does applying ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice supress the error?

Tags: spring, jms, spring-integration, aop

adapter going out to a jms queue. I have some logic that needs to trigger both on successful deliver and on failover so i've hooked the adapter to the ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.

```
<jms:outbound-channel-adapter id="101Out" 
                              channel="101DestinationChannel"
                              connection-factory="101Factory"
                              destination-expression="headers.DESTINATION_NAME"
                              destination-resolver="namingDestinationResolver"
                              explicit-qos-enabled="true">
    <jms:request-handler-advice-chain>
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice">
            <beans:property name="onSuccessExpression" ref="success"/>
            <beans:property name="successChannel" ref="normalOpsReplicationChannel"/>
            <beans:property name="onFailureExpression" ref="failure"/>
            <beans:property name="failureChannel" ref="failoverInitiationChannel" />
        </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean id="retryAdvice" class="org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.RequestHandlerRetryAdvice">>
            <beans:property name="retryTemplate" ref="retryTemplate"/>
        </beans:bean>
    </jms:request-handler-advice-chain>       
</jms:outbound-channel-adapter>
```

Now both of these methods are triggering appropriately and the replication/failover logic is executing fine. But on failure (when i stop the queue manager) once the process hooked up to the failureChannel completes, i see that the error is propagating back to the source of the call (an HTTP endpoint in this case).

The advice IS supposed to stop the error from propagating right?

```
    <service-activator input-channel="failoverInitiationChannel"
        ref="failoverInitiator" />
```

I have a service activator hooked up to the failureChannel which just mutates a singleton. Nothing i do here can have triggered the error. Moreover, the error coming back is definitely for the queue access so it can't be anything i did after the failoverInitiator activated.

```
org.springframework.jms.IllegalStateException: JMSWMQ0018: Failed to connect to queue manager 'APFDEV1' with connection mode 'Client' and host name 'localhost(1510)'.
```

I'm a very confused if i'm supposed to use the recoveryCallback on the RequestHandlerRetryAdvice or this one to actually stop the error. But i do need an action taken even on success so the ExpressionEvaluatingAdvice is a better fit to my scenario.

Thanks for the help in advance :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the default behavior. Please see the  `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` javadocs for the `trapException` property...

```
/**
 * If true, any exception will be caught and null returned.
 * Default false.
 * @param trapException true to trap Exceptions.
 */
public void setTrapException(boolean trapException) {
    this.trapException = trapException;
}
```

I will add a note the reference manual.

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much. I can remove all the ugly error handling i was doing upstream now :-)